# DataBind multiple CheckBoxes to create a bitmask?

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding

I have a set of four CheckBoxes on a form.

For most of my other controls I am databinding their data using commands following the format `myControl.DataBindings.Add("ControlBindingPropertyName", DataSource, "DataSourcePropertyName")` which seems to be working fine.

For my CheckBoxes, though, I'd like to create a bitmask based on which ones are checked/unchecked.

Obviously I can do this naively by creating individual event handlers on each of the boxes' `CheckedChanged` events and setting a value there, but I was wondering if there's any way to incorporate DataBinding, perhaps binding each CheckBox to a property on the form, and then binding that property back to my dataset.

Comment: Do you want the bitmask stored in one field in your dataset or four separate fields?

Comment: One field. It's a column which exists in a currently-active table, so there's no changing it. I'd be happy with booleans, myself, but it's not an option.

Comment: What is the datatype of the bitmask column?

Comment: Datatype is an integer in this case.

Comment: To make this work it sounds like you need to know which checkbox is being changed to change the correct bit in the bitmask.  For example, checkbox 1 manipulates the first position, toggling the bitmask between 1111 and 0111.  Unfortunately, if you bind to a single property, I don't know of a way for that property to discern which checkbox called it.  I do believe you could do this with a single event handler, if that would be a workable solution.